# Is there a way to edit "Usage limits" of all coupons at once?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in Wordpress and have hundreds of coupons. I want Usage limit per user to be 1. Is there ANY WAY out there I can bulk all coupons together and edit the "Usage limit" in one go?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Plugin for this [WooCommerce Extended Coupon Features FREE](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/)

After install and activate this plugin you can see following options in your coupon section admin side.
Using this plugin you can set coupon usage limit per user.

[image]

Hope, This will help you.

Comment: That is my problem. The way it is shown in the picture I will have to go through every single coupon. I want to edit "Usage limit per user" in one click for ALL the coupons. I have not found a way yet so I'm hoping to find an answer here.